# Парсинг телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем добрый день. Возник интересный вопрос. Можно ли спарсить бота в телеграм, написанный в свою очередь на Python? Может в версии веб-страницы можно как-то парсить? Допустим бот написан на Python, могу ли я получить этот код? Допустим html мы можем спарсить со страницы в пару строчек кода, могу ли я спарсить Python код на веб странице? Или это из разряда сказки? Подскажите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: можно, если канал открыт

Comment: канал открыт. А как? Мне нужно парсить не сообщения, а код, на котором бот написан

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Исходный код хранится и исполняется на сервере, Вам передаётся только результат. Нет доступа к серверу — нет доступа к коду.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Подскажите пожалуйста с этим вопросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110189/free-kassa-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82