# Free-kassa на Python телеграм бот

Tags: php, python, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем добрый день. Делаю телеграм бота. Мне нужна ссылка, по которой человек будет переходить и оплачивать товар на free-kassa. Возникла проблема с free-kassa. **Мне нужно сгенерировать ссылку на Python**. На сайте есть документация, но там всё на PHP. Как мне это написать на питоне? Я обратился в тп., сказали что для моего бота виджеты (у них на сайте ожно сделать ссылку и не париться) не подходят, пишите сылку для себя сами. Вот возник вопрос, **как сделать ссылку из PHP в Python?** Подскажите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо! https://www.free-kassa.ru/docs/api.php#form_sign Порекомендовали пользоваться данной инструкцией при генерации ссылки...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала используйте библиотеку: `import hashlib`. В ней можно сделать md5 хеш, который вам нужен:

```
merchant_id = b'7012';
secret_word = b'secret';
order_id = b'154';
order_amount = b'100.11';
sign = merchant_id + b':' + order_amount + b':' + secret_word + b':' + order_id;
h = hashlib.md5();
h.update(sign)

print(h.hexdigest())
```

Вот результат выполнения кода: `33556f2c6a097ac19ae28b807b8fd72a`. Остальная часть - уже форма, в которую вы можете сами подставить значения.